# Corregir advertencia Avoid document.write()

Tags: html5, bootstrap, bootstrap-4, seo

Estoy realizando practicas de SEO para el mejoramiento de mi pagina web y así obtener un buen puntaje haciendo uso de esta herramienta **https://web.dev/measure/** que hasta el momento me es muy útil y me ha ayudado a mejorar mi pagina web como tal, unas de las advertencias como indica el titulo es Avoid document.write()

La descripción del reporte me indica lo siguiente:

> For users on slow connections, external scripts dynamically injected
> via `document.write()` can delay page load by tens of seconds. Learn
> more.

El código en donde cae la advertencia es el siguiente.

```
<div class="text-center p-3 font-weight-bold" style="background-color: #0fb4b0">
Copyright ©
    <script>
      var f = new Date();
   ➜   document.write(f.getFullYear());
    </script>
    Clínica Equilibrium
```

Alguien me podría guiar para la modificación del mismo y poder quitar esa advertencia.

De antemano les agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Usa `innerText` para asignale un valor a una etiqueta HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias por tu guía @BetaM, aunque sea un poco tarde publico la respuesta para cualquier que pase por lo mismo.

```
<div class="text-center p-3 font-weight-bold" id="fechaActual" style="background-color: #0fb4b0">    
<script >      
  var fecha = new Date(); //Fecha actual
  var mes = fecha.getMonth()+1; //obteniendo mes
  var dia = fecha.getDate(); //obteniendo dia
  var ano = fecha.getFullYear(); //obteniendo año
  if(dia<10)
    dia='0'+dia; //agrega cero si el menor de 10
  if(mes<10)
    mes='0'+mes //agrega cero si el menor de 10
  document.getElementById('fechaActual').innerHTML="Copyright © "+ano+" Clínica Equilibrium";    
  </script>
```